# Trying to insert data which is added to my cart in my database which is in array

Tags: php, html

```
case "add":
  if (!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
    $productByCode = $db_handle - > runQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE code='".$_GET["code"]."'");
    $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"] => array('name' => $productByCode[0]["name"], 'code' => $productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity' => $_POST["quantity"], 'price' => $productByCode[0]["price"]));
    if (!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
      if (in_array($productByCode[0]["code"], $_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
          $name = mysql_real_escape_string($v['name']);
          $code = mysql_real_escape_string($v['code']);
          $qunatity = mysql_real_escape_string($v['quantity']);
          $price = mysql_real_escape_string($v['price']);
          $con = mysqli_connect("retail", "RS", "....", "rs");
          $query = "insert into addtocart(name,code,quantity,price)  values('$name','$code','$quantity','$price')";
          mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
          if ($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
        }
      } else {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"], $itemArray);
      }
    } else {
      $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
    }
  }
  break;
```

Comment: i want to add insert query  in this but i amk not able to add insert query can anyone help since i am new to this...........

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: no begging and explain expected and actual result

Comment: Try to echo the insert query like echo 'Query='.$query."<br>"; and see whats happening

Comment: nothing is happening can you elabroate it

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert an array directly to mysql as mysql doesn't understand php data types. Mysql only understands SQL. So to insert an array into a mysql database you have to convert it to an sql statement. This can be done manually or by a library. The output should be an INSERT statement.

Here is a standard mysql insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ....) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2..)
```

If you have a table with name `addtocart` with the columns which are presented in the keys of your array you can insert with this small snippet. Here is how your array is converted to this statement.

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `addtocart`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

I hope it will work for you. Please let me know any error occur..

Comment: thankyou for you reply but i had two table one to fetch data ........(product table) and another one to insert data in cart table can you help me out with this portionif (!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
      if (in_array($productByCode[0]["code"], $_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
       {
          $query = "insert into addtocart(name,code,quantity,price)  values('$name','$code','$quantity','$price')";
          mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());

Comment: if this solve your problem please mark it as an answer and upvote so it will help others in future.

Comment: I tried but again it is not inserting the data into my database could plze overview my code

Comment: $columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($insData));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `addtocart`($columns) VALUES ($values)";                 i tried this but not getting the exact way were to use

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save an array to mysql you must serialize() array then insert to mysql

and when you return it from mysql used unserialize() array its back again to work on it

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php